# Complete table of Italian irregular verbs

Tags: verbs, resources

Is there a *complete* list of all Italian irregular verbs?

I would appreciate it in particular to find a table that includes the various subregularities, too.

Comment: In this web site you can find the the conjugation of most common Italian irregular verbs: http://grammatica-italiana.dossier.net/verbi-irregolari-1-coniugazione.htm

Comment: Sure it is long! ;-)

Answer (score 7):

There is a complete (I believe: it says “i verbi irregolari dell'italiano moderno”), accurately annotated list of Italian irregular verbs in Serianni's Italian grammar, in paragraphs 125-355 of Ch. XI (pages 300-320 in Garzanti edition, *Italiano*; there is also an edition by UTET).

Answer (score 4):

I don't know any online complete list of irregular Italian verbs, but I think a good book is this one: Roberto Tartaglione, ***Verbissimo: tutti i verbi italiani*** (Firenze: Alma Edizioni, 1999), 
http://www.almaedizioni.it/en/catalogue/scheda/verbissimo/.

Answer (score 0):

Good online resources on Italian verbs are the verbix conjugator [verbix.com](https://www.verbix.com/) or [italian-verbs.com](https://www.italian-verbs.com/). All Italian verbs are fully conjugated, both regular and irregular, but occasionally you may find some mistakes. If you are looking for a more reputable source, I recommend [The Big Book of Italian Verbs: 900 Fully Conjugated Verbs in All Tenses...](https://books.google.it/books?id=DYynDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: @ryanmitchell: I notice that you have suggested those websites and that book in at least three different answers. I don't know them, but I don't doubt they are useful. May I only ask whether you are involved in one or more of them?