# "Fare si che" o "fare sì che"

Tags: word-usage, orthography, accents

Buongiorno,

Mi chiedo quali delle seguenti due sia corretto, "fare si che" o "fare sì che". Non sono sicuro di quale sia il costrutto giusto, anche perché non capisco la funzione di "si" o "sì" in questo contesto.

Grazie.

Comment: Penso che [questo post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/9095/707) risponda in parte alla tua domanda.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Come puoi vedere nel punto 1 della voce ["sì" del vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/si/), in italiano esiste un avverbio "sì", scritto con l'accento, di uso arcaico e letterario equivalente a "così". Tuttavia, questo dizionario spiega che l'utilizzo di questo vocabolo con valore consecutivo è oggi ancora vivo in alcune espressioni che possono essere considerate praticamente come cristallizzate, soprattutto dopo il verbo "fare", ma anche seguito dalla preposizione "da" + infinito:

> Con valore consecutivo è ancora dell’uso vivo in alcune espressioni, spec. dopo il verbo *fare*: *bisogna far sì che tutti restino soddisfatti*; o quando è seguito dalla prep. *da* con infinito: *aggiungerò qualche nota, sì da rendere il testo più chiaro* (v. anche *sicché*).

Come si è detto in [questa risposta](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/9095),
il [dizionario Hoepli](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/S/si.php) spiega che la costruzione  "fare che sì che" + congiuntivo ha il significato di "fare in modo che":

> (con il v. al congiunt.) **Fare sì che**, fare in modo che: *fate sì che tutto proceda nel modo stabilito*

Si trova anche sul [dizionario Sabatini Coletti](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/S/si_2.shtml)

> fare sì che, introduce una frase consecutiva-finale: *la sua presenza ha fatto sì che si raggiungesse*

e sul [De Mauro](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/si_4)

> spec. in relazione con ***fare***: ***far sì che, far sì da***, fare in modo che: *devi far sì che tutto si risolva*

Nota che i dizionari Hoepli, Sabatini Coletti e De Mauro hanno una voce propria per questo avverbio "sì" (che a volte ha anche valore di congiunzione) per distinguerlo dell'avverbio affermativo "sì", che si trova in una voce diversa.

Answer (score 4):

Attento a non confondere il **pronome riflessivo** “si” con l’**avverbio** “sì”.

La forma corretta è sicuramente “Far sì che” in quanto “Far si” è una versione errata del verbo riflessivo “Farsi” (“Farsi la doccia.”).

---

Il [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/si-o-si_(La-grammatica-italiana)/) dà un’ottima spiegazione sulla differenza dei due lessemi:

> SI O SÌ? Si tratta di due ➔omonimi.
>
> - Si, senza accento (dal latino se), è il pronome riflessivo atono di 3a persona
>
>   “Si è messo in malattia.”
> - Sì, con l’accento grave (dal latino sic), è l’avverbio di affermazione
>
>   “Hai risposto di sì.”

Comment: Tuttavia, il "sì" della domanda non è l'avverbio di affermazione.

Comment: @Charo si tratta invece proprio dell’avverbio di affermazione. Il Treccani spiega in maniera esaustiva l’abbinamento di questo avverbio con il verbo fare al punto “e” di questa pagina http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/si/ :)

Comment: Lo spiega appunto la voce del Treccani che hai messo nel link: si tratta di un avverbio equivalente a "così".

Comment: @Charo ahhh ho capito cosa intendi. Scusami pensavo ti riferissi al fatto che “Far sì” è una locuzione. Mi spiace ho frainteso il commento >_<. Ho modificato subito la risposta per renderla più chiara :)