# In questa frase bisogna usare il congiuntivo o l'indicativo?

Tags: subjunctive-mood

(1) questo rapporto fa sì che la mediana **sia** sui 19-21mm

oppure

(2) questo rapporto fa sì che la mediana **è** sui 19-21mm.

Grazie a chiunque risponderà

Comment: Usa il congiuntivo!

Comment: Attento: “fa sì”, non *“fa si”.

Comment: Benvenuto su ItalianSE!! E usa il congiuntivo.

Comment: Mi accodo ai benvenuti, ma qualcuno potrebbe scrivere una risposta? (se no lo faccio io stasera...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Come si è detto in [questa risposta](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/10839) e sul [dizionario Hoepli](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/S/si.php),
la costruzione  "fare che sì che" prevede l'uso del congiuntivo:

> (con il v. al congiunt.) **Fare sì che**, fare in modo che: *fate sì che tutto proceda nel modo stabilito*

Anche sul libro [*Viva il congiuntivo!*](https://books.google.es/books?id=x3shMxMWr2UC&pg=PT86&lpg=PT86&dq=%22fare+s%C3%AC+che%22+congiuntivo&source=bl&ots=PW1tdFHWak&sig=ACfU3U1TRb-uVuVgxJrbQZL7qILda0v7lw&hl=ca&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjv24Kmu6blAhVt8OAKHQ2yB0AQ6AEwCHoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22fare%20s%C3%AC%20che%22%20congiuntivo&f=false), di Valeria Della Valle e Giuseppe Patota, si può leggere:

> Il congiuntivo compare di regola anche nelle frasi dipendenti da fare sì che.
>
> - Il meccanismo di riscaldamento fa sì che l'aria venga scaldata automaticamente.

Quindi, dovresti scrivere

> Questo rapporto fa sì che la mediana sia sui 19-21 mm.