# Verbi irregolari coniugati

Tags: verbs, resources

Buongiorno,

I francesi hanno un libro che si chiama *Le Bécherelle* dove sono sinterizzati tutti i verbi irregolari francesi ed i suoi derivati.

Quanti verbi irregolari esistono in italiano e dove posso trovare una lista di tutti questi, con tutte le tabelle di tutte le loro coniugazioni?

Grazie.

Comment: I think your question is a duplicate of this one: https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/2285/complete-table-of-italian-irregular-verbs.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that Serianni's *Grammatica* (one of the answers in the linked question) was explicitly modeled on Grevisse's *Bon usage*